# What is Ethical Witnessing?

Tags: vocabulary

What exactly is "Ethical Witnessing"? What does it mean?

**Some Context**

We're reading a poetry book in school - about the Holocaust. So these Jews, and other people being abused and tortured played a part in the "Ethical witnessing." I also have to relate it to a personal experience, but what is it?

Comment: Did you google for it? 'witnessing' is a public exposition of ones faith (def 4 on freedictionary). Ethical witnessing is presumably analogous not for faith but for ethically charged situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**An Ethical Witness**:

is a person who has seen things that are of ethical importance, like the one you mentioned, having humanitarian implications and relevance to social and justice issues.

The importance of *Ethical Witnessing* is that it provides testimonial  evidence of very serious events that otherwise would be difficult or impossible to prove.